# How to refer a third party theme as attribute in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android

Currently, I have a 3rd party theme used in my `AndroidManifest.xml`.

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/Theme.JStock.Light" >

    <!-- 3rd party library with 3rd party theme -->
    <activity
        android:name="group.pals.android.lib.ui.lockpattern.LockPatternActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="user"
        android:theme="@style/Alp.Theme.Light" />
```

### themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.JStock.Light" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        ...
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.JStock.Dark" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Dark">
        ...
    </style>
```

Since, I may change my app theme during runtime

`setTheme(R.style.Theme.JStock.Light);` or `setTheme(R.style.Theme.JStock.Dark);`

I wish to have something like below, so that my Java code need not take care on the 3rd party theme.

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@style/Theme.JStock.Light" >

    <!-- 3rd party library with 3rd party theme -->
    <activity
        android:name="group.pals.android.lib.ui.lockpattern.LockPatternActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="user"
        android:theme="?attr/thirdPartyTheme" />
```

### themes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.JStock.Light" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="thirdPartyTheme">@style/Alp.Theme.Light</item>
        ...
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.JStock.Dark" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Dark">
        <item name="thirdPartyTheme">@style/Alp.Theme.Dark</item>
        ...
    </style>
```

Of course, this will cause run-time error. May I know, what is the proper way to achieve so?

Comment: I don't see how do you want that to work, you're trying to set a theme based on an attribute from a theme(one which supposedly is already the current theme).

Comment: So, do you have any idea, how I can change the theme for non-main Activity (LockPatternActivity), without calling setTheme(R.style.Alp.Theme.Light); during its onCreate. I wish I can handle all these in main Activity level, without going through each child Activities.